# Should we rename the Plugins tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sorry, I'm new to SE, but I've noticed that the "Plugins" tag is defined with respect to DAWs, and does not include video applications (editing apps, compositing apps, 3d animation apps, etc) in its scope.  Rather than adding video stuff to its scope, I think it might be more helpful to change the name from "Plugins" to "Audio Plugins", and create a separate "Video Plugins" tag.  Is this "meta" area the appropriate place to recommend altering the tag name?  Is it even possible to alter a tag name?  Would it just be better to expand the scope of "plugins"?

Comment: Welcome to AVP and good question!  You might consider changing the title of your question to illustrate that you're proposing a change to the Plugins tag.

Comment: No need to apologize for being new:)  We welcome suggestions from all users.  We are especially glad to get a fresh view of things.  We're glad your here.

Answer (score 2):

This *is* the appropriate place to offer suggestions and ideas for changes to the site.

On beta sites like this one, you need 150 rep to create new tags, and 200 rep to edit a question's tags.  See the [privileges section of the faq](https://video.stackexchange.com/privileges).

As to your suggestion in particular, I agree that the tag wiki either focuses the tag where it shouldn't, or is just named wrong given what the wiki describes.

My thoughts here would be to generalize the plugins tag.  It should generically describe a software editing component.

I think any question that required the use of the [plugins](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) tag would already be otherwise tagged for audio or video, or it would be obvious. (something like [premiere](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/premiere)[plugins](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugins) wouldn't require [video-plugins](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-plugins) to get the point across).

I'd be more than happy to suggest an edit to the tag wiki.  I'll wait and see what others think about this first though.

Comment: +1  I agree that the tag wiki should be edited to include both and the tag should remain plugins.  I also think it should be obvious by the other tags whether audio or video is implied.

Comment: I've suggested an edit to the wiki excerpt.